# An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation - linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple query,

```
            var RoundList = (from t1 in entities.RPlays.AsNoTracking()
                             where t1.Start.ToString("d") == "01/03/2017" && t1.VId == 32
                             select new
                             {
                                 TimePlayed = t1.TimePlayed,
                                 MatchPlayed = t1.MatchPlayed 
                             });
```

that gets me the message "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" but it doesn't say where :(

I get the problem on the `where` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check any of the numerous other questions with the exact same problem?

Comment: I'd guess it's the `ToString`.  Why not compare to a `DateTime` or just compare the month, day, and year parts separately.

Comment: Maybe convert your "01/03/2017" to a datetime variable and use a typed comparison rather than a string conversion.

Comment: @tnw I've already checked the other numerous questions with the exact same problem

Comment: If you take parts of the query out of the code I'm sure it will let you know which is the problem, but it probably is the ToString("d") like @juharr as said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the `ToString("d")`.

You should try to just compare dates like this:

```
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-01");
        var RoundList = (from t1 in entities.RPlays.AsNoTracking()
                         where t1.Start == myDate && t1.VId == 32
                         select new
                         {
                             TimePlayed = t1.TimePlayed,
                             MatchPlayed = t1.MatchPlayed 
                         });
```

Comment: Actually might need to do `t1.Start.Date == myDate` so that the time is truncated, that or compare the `DateTime` parts separately.

Comment: That's true,indeed!